# Get-ChildItem to find last logged on user

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

This post for using get-childitem to find last logged on user was quite helpful, [Powershell - last logged on user - same input, different output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488892/powershell-last-logged-on-user-same-input-different-output)

However, I am running into some problems.

I am writing the following command:

```
Get-Childitem c:\users\*\ntuser.dat -force | select-object -last 1 {(Split-path $_.directory -leaf)},last* | sort lastwritetime -descending
```

It gives output in the form

```
(Split-path $_.directory -leaf) : jjoe
LastAccessTime                  : 10/10/2013 11:37:14 AM
LastAccessTimeUtc               : 10/10/2013 3:37:14 PM
LastWriteTime                   : 10/10/2013 1:51:02 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc                : 10/10/2013 5:51:02 PM
```

How do I make this output jjoe instead of all those lines?

I tried

```
$abc = Get-Childitem c:\users\*\ntuser.dat -force | select-object -last 1 {(Split-path $_.directory -leaf)},last* | sort lastwritetime -descending 

$abc.(Split-path $_.directory -leaf)
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
{(Split-path $_.directory -leaf)},last*
```

With this:

```
@{ n='Username'; e={ Split-path $_.directory -leaf } },last*
```

Then the property is named on the pipeline and you can then do:

```
<your script> | Select -Expand UserName
```

Explanation:
`@{Name=$StringVaue; Expression=$ScriptBlock}` is how you can add `Calculated Properties` to `Select-Object`. Short Form `@{n=$StringValue; e=$ScriptBlock}`

Comment: Wow, Calculated Properties!

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the name without `Split-Path`. The Directory property is a System.IO.DirectoryInfo object so you could get its name property:

```
... @{n='Username'; e={$_.Directory.Name }}
```